DeleteDuplicates By Proportionality
I have a list of expressions and I would like to delete "duplicates" that are proportional to each other where the (simplified) proportionality constant satisfies NumericQ. What would be the best way to achieve this?
(I.e. keep only one element (doesn't matter which) per equivalence class $a \equiv b$ if $a = c b $ with $c \in \mathbb{R}$.)

You haven't given a comprehensive list of test cases, so here is a solution which may or may not work for you.
list = {2 a, 3 a, 4 a, 5 b, 6 b, 2 a + 3 b, 8 c};
DeleteDuplicates[list, RealValuedNumericQ@*Divide]
(* {2 a, 5 b, 2 a + 3 b, 8 c} *)

You can replace RealValuedNumericQ, which was introduced in 13.3, with NumericQ if you are not dealing with any complex numbers.

Thanks! This failed on my test case (yes sorry not included) but inserting a composition of FullSimplify did the trick. ClearAll[deleteDuplicatesProportional]; deleteDuplicatesProportional[ls_] :=    DeleteDuplicates[ls, NumericQ@*FullSimplify@*Divide]
